# How can I get spring data to save a "getter" as a mongodb field?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Question:

- How can I get spring data to save a "getter" as a mongodb field?

Context:

- The Score java object has a 'getAverageFare()' method that performs calculations
- Another object (i.e which implements @Document) has Score as a field
- The goal: spring data, when it saves the Parent document adds an `averageFare` field and populates it with result getAverageFare()

I've tried @Field annotation

```
@Field("averageFare")
public BigDecimal getAverageFare() {
    return fareTotal.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(getCount()), RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you store the Score as a nested document of the Another object?

Comment: @goooooooo no. Another object has a Score field called 'score'.

Comment: @goooooooo My error. The term "document" as in "nested document" threw me off.
I believe the answer to this question:

Q :Do you store the Score as a nested document of the Another object?

Is actually "yes". 

In java we define it as follows. Spring /jpa handles the 'mapping to mongo'

public class Another {
   .....define fields...
  Score score
}

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to store data, not methods. You can run that calculation in the layer above. The entity class is supposed to be a POJO and the annotation `@Field("averageFare")` can be added on the field itself rather than on the method. You can have the method you show as a utility method which would always get you the average `on the fly` rather than store it in the db. If you need it stored, just add the `averageFare` instance type **field** and in the setter you can perform that calculation - then you don't need the getter calculations anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Move the calculation logic from getter to setter. It assures the field has its value as intended and the repository operates with the calculated data.

```java
@Field("averageFare")
String averageFare;

public void setAverageFare(BigDecimal averageFare) {
    if (averageFare == null || this.averageFare == null || this.fareTotal == null) {
        // set if the calculation would fail on NPE
        this.averageFare = averageFare;
    } else {
        // otherwise perform the calculation
        this.averageFare = this.fareTotal.divide(
                BigDecimal.valueOf(getCount()), 
                RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN); 
    }
}

public BigDecimal getAverageFare() {
    return averageFare;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Define the field 'averageFare' in the POJO (as any other member)

```
private BigDecimal averageFare;
```

2. Create the method to calculate its value

```
public void calculateAverageFare() {
  this.averageFare = this.fareTotal.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(getCount()), RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
}
```

3. Create a custom Mongo event listener

```
package your.package;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AbstractMongoEventListener;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.BeforeConvertEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class YourEntityListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener {
  @Override
  public void onBeforeConvert(BeforeConvertEvent event) {
    super.onBeforeConvert(event);
    YourEntity entity = event.getSource();
    entity.calculateAverageFare();
  }
}
```

Thus, each time th documebnt is is updated, the calculated field will be automatically persisted in the DB.